# how to use c# For(;;) in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

please how can I use this c# loop in parallel mode:

```
for (int j = 0; ; )
{
// do something
}
```

I have tried many times without any solution!

Answer (score 2):

A simple google search yeilded the following result:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You want to use `Parallel.For`, and that link gives you a detailed example.

Comment: I mean how to use parallel for without increment or condition like this : for(int j=0,,)